# Error function query

Tags: custom-post-types

I’m trying to show a custom post type called `CursosTL` but I’m getting an error when using the following code.

```
function elc_cursos_en_el_blog() {
 
 if ( $query->is_home() && $query->is_main_query() ) {
  $query->set( 'post_type', array( 'post', 'CursoTL' ));
 }

}
add_action( 'pre_get_posts', 'elc_cursos_en_el_blog' );
```

The error is:

````
Stack trace:  
#0 wp-includes/class-wp-hook.php(287): elc_cursos_en_el_blog(Object(WP_Query))  
#1 wp-includes/class-wp-hook.php(311): WP_Hook->apply_filters('', Array)  
#2 wp-includes/plugin.php(551): WP_Hook->do_action(Array)  
#3 wp-includes/class-wp-query.php(1779): do_action_ref_array('pre_get_posts', Array)  
#4 wp-includes/class-wp-query.php(3448): WP_Query->get_posts()  
#5 wp-includes/post.php(2065): WP_Query->query(Array)  
#6 wp-content/plugins/amp/includes/admin/functions.php(```
````

Any help? PHP is version 7.4.

Answer (score 3):

You have to pass in the `$query` variable to use it in your function; if you don't, PHP uses `null`.

Try:

```
function elc_cursos_en_el_blog( $query ) {
 
 if ( $query->is_home() && $query->is_main_query() ) {
  $query->set( 'post_type', array( 'post', 'CursoTL' ));
 }

}
add_action( 'pre_get_posts', 'elc_cursos_en_el_blog' );
```

See [`pre_get_posts`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/pre_get_posts/) for the hook's documentation.